# Is there a way to use rosjava in ROS noetic

Tags: java, android, ros

I want to make mobile control inteface in my robot .So I make a mobile application , but ros java did not install .

When I try to install, I get the package not found error.

$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-rosjava

[sudo] password for abdulsamet: Reading package lists...
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information...
Done E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-rosjava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop in ROS_JAVA without installing rosjava. In fact, [ROS Java contains a plain java, standalone version of roscore that does not require any ROS installation to be present.](https://spyroskoukas.com/2020/05/15/how-to-setup-a-ros-java-system-in-windows/)
All you need is to use the required dependencies in your dependency management system. In fact if you only plan to develop in ROS Java you do not need to install ROS at all in your PC. I have been perfectly able to develop in windows using ROS Java for many years now.

This is a [related](https://spyroskoukas.com/2020/05/15/how-to-setup-a-ros-java-system-in-windows/) short article where I get the information, I had written this article some time ago. It also contains some complete examples of that should run anywhere a java program can run.